# Complete UI Redesign in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I've been tasked with starting a complete UI redesign for an App that is already coded in **Ruby on Rails**.  Honestly, I'm not sure where to start.  Would it be easier to start from scratch or go through and modify the existing code?

The issue I see with modifying the existing code is that there are legacy artifacts that could conflict with the new *UI* code (**CSS** classes, ids, styling, etc.) which would make the redesign project probably take longer.

The issue I see with starting from scratch is that I'd literally start from scratch.  There are existing migrations that I'd have to re-run by first clearing out the *DB*, which I can't do on a production server.  Re-run all of the install scripts (like Devise, Rubber, etc.).

Has anyone gone through this before?  Any recommended things to do?

Can I just hook into the existing *DB* and not have to run any migrations (since I can't do that in production)?  Surely ppl that do this have some trick to getting back up and running smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned UI redesign, I wonder how that affects the DB. However, generally my approach to such would be to first do a HTML/CSS design to show how the new UI would look, both with and without data, then break those HTML down into components or partials then, I'd start replacing old components with the new components. I'd probably start from the root route and build up.

You shouldn't really need to clear out DBs or anything of sorts, I prefer to use SQLite for local development. If you'd like to test with data, you should probably find a way of seeding some of the data or copying data from the main application to your localDB. I'd never advice that you use your production DB with your development environment.

Just thought to share my 2 cents.

Comment: Ultimately, it doesn't affect my DB... I guess I'm trying to figure out whether I should start a new RoR folder like `new_ui`, whereas all of the old files for the app are in `old_ui`.

Comment: I don't think you should start a new RoR project. If it is version controlled, you should branch out(checkout a new branch) and start from there. It could be daunting but I think it's always worth it.

Comment: Yeah, that was were I was leaning since it is version controlled.  I guess I'll just do that, delete all of the 'content' relevant to the page and go from there.